# How to create a weighted edgelist directed from a pandas dataframe with weights in two columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame (df):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 'B', '1'],
    ['A', 'B', '2'],
    ['B', 'A', '41'],
    ['A', 'C', '11'],
    ['C', 'B', '3'],
    ['B', 'D', '4'],
    ['D', 'B','51']
    ], columns=('station_i', 'station_j','UID'))
```

I used

```
>>> df2=df.groupby(by=['station_i', 'station_j']).size().to_frame(name = 'counts_ij').reset_index()
```

to obtain the dataframe `df2`:

```
>>> print(df2)
  station_i station_j  counts_ij
0         A         B          2
1         A         C          1
2         B         A          1
3         B         D          1
4         C         B          1
5         D         B          1
```

Now, I would obtain the dataframe `df3`, build as shown below, where couples with same values, but reversed, are dropped and counted in an extra column as showed below:

```
>>>print(df3)
  station_i station_j counts_ij counts_ji
0         A         B         2         1
1         A         C         1         0
2         C         B         1         0
3         B         D         1         1
```

Would really appreciate some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# find out indices that are reverse duplicated
dupe = pd.concat([
    np.maximum(df2.station_i, df2.station_j), 
    np.minimum(df2.station_i, df2.station_j)
], axis=1).duplicated()
 
df2[dupe]
  station_i station_j  counts_ij
2         B         A          1
5         D         B          1
 
df2[~dupe]
  station_i station_j  counts_ij
0         A         B          2
1         A         C          1
3         B         D          1
4         C         B          1

# split by dupe, reverse the dupe station and merge with the non dupe
df2[~dupe].merge(
    df2[dupe].rename(
        columns={'station_i': 'station_j', 'station_j': 'station_i', 'counts_ij': 'counts_ji'}
    ), how='left'
).fillna(0).astype({'counts_ji': int})
  station_i station_j  counts_ij  counts_ji
0         A         B          2          1
1         A         C          1          0
2         B         D          1          1
3         C         B          1          0
```